# List field names of a model as choices in the field of another model

Tags: django, django-models

Unfortunately, I cant find exactly what I need but I know it requires `get_fields()`

Id am guessing I would need a method call to create the list of field names :

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ModelB(models.Model):
    fields = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              choices=field_names_of_modela())

    def field_names_of_modela():
        return [field.name for field in ModelA._meta.get_fields()]
```

The above code wont work... Is there a way to get field names of another model as a list in this model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

include the function between two models

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   
def field_names_of_modela():
    return [(field.name, field.verbose_name ) for field in ModelA._meta.get_fields()]
           
 

class ModelB(models.Model):
    fields = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,
                                  choices=field_names_of_modela())
```

also as according to documentions:

> Field.choices
>
> A sequence consisting itself of iterables of exactly  two items (e.g.
> [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for this  field.

Comment: tried that before i posted and got  ..../lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 866, in get_choices
    choices = list(self.choices)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I already had tried that too :) and got ackages/django/apps/registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

Comment: ok, again i updated it

Comment: i renamed fields to quotefields. so: quotefields = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.quotefields.choices = field_names_of_modela(self). but i get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'choices'

Comment: I dont see anywhere in your code where you refer to ModelA model... you have instance there though.